# Is there a difference in efficiency between running queries as in-line text or by substitution?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

This might be a novice's obsession to optimize that which should be left alone, but I've been struggling a bit with how much work to perform in application code and how much in SQLite queries. I've tried to push as much as possible into queries figuring that SQLite C code will handle it far better than I could. Now I have a large set of queries stored in a namespace and some in-line with a lot of `:varName` type substitution; and, although everything seems to be working fine thus far, as the code grows I wonder if I'm handling this correctly.

When Tcl first reads a script and converts at least some of it to byte code, is there any difference between including the query text in SQLite `db eval` statements versus storing the query in a namespace variable, especially when they include `:varName` type substitution and the `$::SQL::queryName` string is never going to change? For example,

```
proc DoSomethingChallenging {} {
  lassign [db eval $::SQL::sortOfLongQuery] a b c
  lassign [db eval { 
     with recursive ...  
     ...
     where data_key <> :endKey
  }] a b c
}
```

Could the interpreter, perhaps, not be able to perform some optimization because it msut treat `$::SQL::sortOfLongQuery` as something that could change between procedure calls?

Likewise, I have sets of about ten procedures each that update the database tables in almost identical manner apart from the order of the queries and the way the variables are calculated. In other words the queries are the same but the `:varNames` are different. So far, I've kept the queries in-line in the `db eval {}` statements in each procedure because it would be rather confusing to attempt to alter the names of the variables to be consistent across all procedures; but they could be assigned to new variable names just before running the queries, such that the text could be replaced with a `$::SQL::queryName`; or those variable names could be passed to another procedure that reads them into consistent names and runs the query from that context.

Apart from reducing the lines of code in each procedure, is there any value in attempting to do this? The prepared-statements cache of SQLite might be smaller since the query strings would be identical since the `:varNames` would be consistent across procedure calls. But would adding additional variable names or procedures just to call the queries differently result in unnecessary additional work for Tcl?

Thank you for considering my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It essentially makes no difference in this case; though there is a cache, it is entirely within the extension. (The SQL text acts as a key into the cache as well as being the thing that is compiled; that's not the only way Tcl implementations may cache things, but it is the relevant one here.) It is, however, mostly considered to be good style to have the SQL as immediate literals where possible, and for several reasons:

1. It's *extremely* good practice to have SQL in a (substitution-free) literal with parameters where required. (Applies to other languages too.) This avoids a *lot* of hazards with SQL injection.
2. Having the SQL be visible in the same area as where the Tcl variables to use as parameters are is clearer to read. (On the other hand, putting the SQL elsewhere might make some types of testing easier...)

To emphasise, **it does not make a noticeable performance difference.** The cost of looking up one variable is usually quite a bit lower than the cost of executing SQL of real complexity, especially anything that ends up having to do I/O. (The costs will be more similar with an in-memory DB.)

You can verify my assertions about performance with the `time` command if you wish.